# How to manually organize files and folders in NetBeans?

Tags: java, ide, netbeans

I'd like to be able to manually adjust placement of objects in a project browser tree in netbeans. Reorder, introduce virtual folders, etc. Is it possible? Is there a plugin providing this functionality? Or should I try another IDE?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that NB has that functionality.... yet.

Before you invest in learning a different IDE, please file an issue that describes the functionality that you were looking for: http://netbeans.org/community/issues.html

(That is how open source improves)